# Date command with zsh

Tags: date, zsh

I'm trying to use the `date` command to output today's date in the format `%d.%m.%y-%H:%M:%S`. Obviously I just do that like this:

```
date +%d.%m.%y-%H:%M:%S
```

This works fine in bash and I get the output I'd expect, but when I do this in zsh I get what I'd expect prefixed by '7m', for example

> 7m07.09.12-16:49:37

instead of

> 07.09.12-16:49:37

I also get an alert from my terminal. This is caused by the `%S` for seconds, because when I take that off the end of the command I don't get the '7m' (but obviously I'm missing the seconds off the end of the date).

Can anyone explain why this happens?

EDIT: extra information: I'm on OS X 10.8 and with zsh 4.3.11, oh-my-zsh installed

Comment: Not quite a full answer, as I don't know `zsh` well. The "%S" seems to be evaluated by `zsh` as something before it is passed to `date`. Simple single- and double-quoting don't prevent it, but the slightly tricky `date '+%d.%m.%y-%H:%H%'S` does. (Note I put the S outside the quotes.)

Comment: Ah you're right! I've only looked at it briefly but I think there's some information on it [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html)

Comment: For what it's worth, I am using zsh 4.3.11 on Linux Mint and that command worked OK for me.

Comment: Could `7m` be part of a terminal control sequence? Try piping the output through `cat -v`. And what happens if you replace `date` by `/bin/echo`?

Comment: Try `unsetopt prompt_percent` and then run the command. I bet the 7m will vanish, but your prompt is likely to get borked.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here - Mac OS X 10.7, zsh 4.3.11.  Perhaps you have some setting that is affecting it?  The prompt stuff shouldn't affect command arguments.  But you could try enclosing the format string in quotation marks to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and could solve it by commenting out line 12 of .oh-my-zsh/lib/termsupport.zsh as suggested at https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/521

Answer (score 27):

One workaround is to wrap the code around `echo $(...)`. It produces the right output and was acceptable for me. Your original command would look like:

```
echo $(date +%d.%m.%y-%H:%M:%S)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you have copied CTRL chars somewhere. 
7m is a control code to reset.
Look for ^[[7m when you are editing.

If you just want the time then ZSH has a nice %*

if you want date and time then try 
RPS1='%W %*'

If you like it, then put it in PS1 or wherever you like.